# What is the exact algorithm does YALMIP use when solving SDP programming?

Tags: matlab

I'm solving a SDP (semidefinite program) problem. I have read some examples using [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/) package in MATLAB. But I can not find a explanation for what the algorithms that YALMIP use. Is that a certain Interior Point Method?

Answer (score 2):

YALMIP does not implement any solution algorithm as it is a modelling language which interfaces external solvers. You will have to study the particular solver you are using (all of the interfaced SDP solvers are interior-point solvers)

https://yalmip.github.io/tags/#semidefinite-programming-solver